# How to fixed right hand side div with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inside row two individual div how can one right hand side dive **fixed** when scrolling page then fixed and when come footer area then up this fixed div.

This is my code example below:

I want **col-md-4** class fixed when come footer content then up.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo- http://jsfiddle.net/3RkM3/41/

**Layout-**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 content">Content</div> 
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
            <div class="fixed col-xs-4">
              Something
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Would you please tell me when scrolling come footer area then div content up how to fix?